# ¿Como mostrar un valor de un ComboBox en javafx pasando un valor?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

amigos estoy realizando una aplicación en javafx la cual tiene que realizar las operaciones CRUD, ahora tengo un combobox con el nombre tipodocumento, ahora capturo la información y la guardo todo bien, al momento de actualizar los datos no e podido hacer que el combobox me muestre el valor deseado
pues asi es como lleno el combobox

```
TipoDocumentos.getItems().addAll(
            "Cedula de ciudadania",
            "Tarjeta de identidad",
            "Pasaporte",
            "Cedula de extranjeria"
    );
```

y asi es como capturo la información

```
String documen = (String) TipoDocumentos.getValue();
```

pues soy nuevo en javafx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que trabajar con el SelectionModel del ComboBox. Por ejemplo, para seleccionar un item cualquiera (vamos a decir por ejemplo "Pasaporte") deberás hacer:

```
TipoDocumentos.getSelectionModel().select("Pasaporte");
```

Tambien puedes hacerlo por índice dentro de los items del combo, por ejemplo para seleccionar de nuevo "Pasaporte" pero de otro modo:

```
TipoDocumentos.getSelectionModel().select(2);
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que para obtener el valor seleccionado utilices mejor los métodos que proporciona el SelectionModel:

```
TipoDocumentos.getSelectionModel(). getSelectedItem();
```

Un saludo y espero que te resulte de utilidad.

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo almacenas en una variable?

Answer (score 0):

**ComboBox usa java generics <>**

Se le puede pasar cualquier objeto , pero combobox llama `toString` del objeto para poner texto en su casilla . una manera es hacer overriding sobre `to string` . Así se pueden usar con objetos no tan solo con primitivos o Strings . Aquí se puede obtener todo el objeto del tipo Person seleccionado en combobox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo funcional de javafx en una sola clase

```
    public class App extends Application {
        
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox();
        
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
        new Person("Alan","Amonnia avenue"),
        new Person("John","Abey road"),
        new Person("Bruce", "Philadelphia sts" )        
        );
        Label name = new Label();
        Label addres = new Label();
        
        
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(( ov, t,  t1) -> {
            name.setText(t1.getName());
            addres.setText(t1.getAddress());
           
            
        });
        
        
        VBox vBox = new VBox(name,addres,comboBox);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
                
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
            
    
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class Person {

        private String name, address;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public Person(String name, String address) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }
        @override
        public String toString (){
        return name ;}    
    }

}
```

---

**con setCellFactory**

Aquí no se necesita   hacer @override en `toString` . A `ListCell` y `ButtonCell`
se le indican que su texto viene de `getName` de Person , no de `toString` como lo hace por defecto. De esta manera se puede insertar un contenido gráfico , aquí solo hay un circulo verde de ejemplo , pero se puede usar una imagen (por ejemplo)

[image: cell]

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox();

        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Alan", "Amonnia avenue"),
                new Person("John", "Abey road"),
                new Person("Bruce", "Philadelphia sts")
        );
        comboBox.setButtonCell(new ListCell<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                if (person != null) {
                    setText(person.getName());
                    setGraphic(new Circle(5, Color.GREENYELLOW));
                    setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }

            }
        });
        comboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<Person> e) -> {
            final ListCell<Person> listCell = new ListCell<>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(person, empty);
                    if (person != null) {
                        setText(person.getName());
                        setGraphic(new Circle(5, Color.GREENYELLOW));
                        setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }

                }
            };
            return listCell;
        });
        Label name = new Label();
        Label addres = new Label();

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            name.setText(t1.getName());
            addres.setText(t1.getAddress());

        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(name, addres, comboBox);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class Person {

        private String name, address;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public Person(String name, String address) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }
       
    }

}
```